# How to detect end of speech in ResponsiveVoice JS

Tags: javascript, responsivevoice

I'm working with the [ResponsiveVoice](http://responsivevoice.org/api/) text to speech library.

Everything is working perfectly fine except there seems to be no way of detecting the end of speech in the API.

On the `responsiveVoice` object I'm able to see the `OnFinishedPlaying` callback but it doesn't work. Neither does the `onend` [callback mentioned here.](http://responsivevoice.org/text-to-speech-sdk/using-callbacks/)

Right now I'm using the `setInterval` to poll on `isPlaying` method to detect the end of speech. However it would be great if there was a method to do so properly.

[Here's the code on Github](https://github.com/ConsciousObserver/VoiceMathlete) that I'm working with.

And here's a minimal [JSFiddle test code](https://jsfiddle.net/j6tpod5k/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mentioned `onend` callback is working if you put the options object as the 3rd parameter:

```
responsiveVoice.speak('Responsive Voice is ready', 'UK English Male', {onend: yourCallbackGoesHere});
```

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j6tpod5k/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I didn't pay attention to the usage and used `onend` directly on the object.